# Validar caixa de texto para que tenha 9 números e apenas possa começar por 9 ou 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, formulário

Boa tarde,

Necessitava criar uma validação de uma caixa de texto em que é obrigatório ser só números e que comece obrigatoriamente por 9 ou 2 e tenha também obrigatoriamente 9 números. Alguém me dá uma luz de como fazer?

o formulário é este :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="telefone">Telefone: <span id="erro-localidade"></span></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telefone" name="telefone">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email address:</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
</div>
<button type="submit" id="submeterForm1" class="btn btn-default">Enviar</button>
```

Tentei usando o match como o amigo rray disse mas no console log me dá sempre null

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$( "#submeterForm1" ).click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();


var telefone = $('#telefone').val();


console.log(telefone.match(/^(9|2)\d{8}$/))

if (telefone.match(/^(9|2)\d{8}$/) == false || telefone == "" || telefone == null) {
    $("#erro-telefone").html("<b style='color:red;'>Por favor preencha o seu telefone correctamente.</b>");
};




});
```

Obrigado

Comment: Se tiver mais de 9 números ele valida ou diz que é inválido?

Comment: Se tiver mais de 9 números é inválido

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode usar uma expressão regular para fazer isso,

```
"988888888".match(/^(9|2)\d{8}$/);
```

`^` define quais caracteres devem estar no inicio da linha nesse caso 9 ou 2 (`(9|2)` o pipe funciona como um OR/OU) que são seguidos de 8 digitos(0-9), quem define a quantidade é o número entre as chaves (`{8}`)

Ou alternativamente:

```
"212345678".match(/^[29]\d{8}$/);
```

Comment: funcionou obrigado :D